# PYTHONPATH is not read by IPython when installed via Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, ipython, homebrew

I installed IPython and Python 3 by using Homebrew on a clean macOS Catalina (virtual machine).

```
$ brew install ipython
```

As the `ipython` package is dependent on the `python3` package, Homebrew installs `ipython` and `python3` together.

```
$ brew info ipython 
ipython: stable 7.13.0 (bottled), HEAD
Interactive computing in Python
https://ipython.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.13.0 (2,905 files, 21.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-04-15 at 18:48:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ipython.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: python ✔, zeromq ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 11,543 (30 days), 33,591 (90 days), 98,995 (365 days)
install-on-request: 5,404 (30 days), 15,768 (90 days), 49,364 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I expected that both of these two commands read `PYTHONPATH` from my shell environment, because `ipython` works so when it is installed by `pip3 install ipython`.

However `ipython` and `python3` installed by using Homebrew have different `sys.path` settings.

```
$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$ ipython 
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys; sys.path                                                                                            
Out[1]: 
['/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.13.0/libexec/bin',
 '',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.13.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.13.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.13.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/oxon/.ipython']

$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; sys.path
['', '/Users/oxon/root-6.20.02/obj/lib', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Q1. Why are they different?

Q2. Is this an expected behavior?

Q3. Why IPython reads `PYTHONPATH` when it is installed by `pip3 install ipython`?

Comment: Rather than `which ipython`, consider using `type ipython` and `type python3`

Comment: Note also that `ipython` is just a regular text file which you can look in with `more "$(which ipython)"`

Comment: Note also that `Python` reads `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` which could result in different behaviour.

Comment: install it with pyenv and pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to [the following line](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/0b738b77a5a13a66a52d76d34c4f608b719e0485/Formula/ipython.rb#L136) in the Homebrew recipe for `ipython`:

```ruby
bin.env_script_all_files(libexec/"bin", :PYTHONPATH => ENV["PYTHONPATH"])
```

It creates the `/usr/local/bin/ipython` script that sets `PYTHONPATH` to a fixed value that is needed for IPython to work properly (since its modules are outside the default Python module directory) before calling the `ipython` executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.14.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.14.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.8/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.14.0/libexec/bin/ipython" "$@"
```

It simply overrides your set value of `PYTHONPATH`. You may modify the script to read:

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/...
```

This will make it append to your `PYTHONPATH` instead of completely overriding it, but the file will be overwritten when the Homebrew package is updated or reinstalled. Therefore, it is advisable to instead put in the IPython startup directory `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` a script, say `root.py` that looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/oxon/root-6.20.02/obj/lib')
```

When you install `ipython` using `pip`, its modules go into the default Python module directory, be it the system one or the user one or the one in the virtual environment, and it is not necessary to mess with `PYTHONPATH` for `ipython` to function correctly.

I'd say the answer to **Q2** is therefore that it's probably a bug and you may submit an issue with Homebrew on GitHub, although I wouldn't hold my breath given how they treated [the same issue with Jupyter](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31325).

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation that answers my Homebrew-specific question. As you wrote, `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ipython-7.14.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz` indeed has an `ipython` bash script that executes `ipython/7.14.0/libexec/bin/ipython` after initializing `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Indeed, the bottle is just a prebuilt version of that same Homebrew recipe.

Answer (score -1):

**Q1. Why are they (i.e., `sys.path`) different?**

The way `sys.path` is populated is typically:
1) the current working directory, followed by 2) directories listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, followed by 3) installation-dependent default paths, which are controlled by the `site` module.
From https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html : **`PYTHONPATH`**: Augment the default search path for module files.
See also e.g.,
https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html
https://realpython.com/lessons/module-search-path/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/search-paths?view=vs-2019

Therefore, each python installation may have its own `sys.path`.
In addition, `sys.path` does not need to be equal to `PYTHONPATH`

Check in each of the two (or three?) cases also the value and post back:

```
import os
print( 'PYTHONPATH = ', os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] )
```

For instance, I have spyder3 and python3.8 under Ubuntu 20.04. When started at the same CLI each has its own `sys.path`, both "derived" from the same `PYTHONPATH`.

**Q2. Is this an expected behavior?**

Yes.

**Q3. Why IPython reads `PYTHONPATH` when it is installed by `pip3 install ipython`?**

Please post the value of `PYTHONPATH` (`$ echo $PYTHONPATH`) prior to executing either of the pythons at the CLI. It is not evident that they are or are not reading its value.

Please post back if this helps finding the cause.